# the parameterized query was not supplied default vs method

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio

I'm using visual studio to make a front end database for my work. However I am currently receiving the error

> " The parameterized query '(@IsNull_Company int,@Original_Company
>   sql_variant,@IsNull_Conta' expects the parameter '@IsNull_Company',
>   which was not supplied."

When I try to delete something off the server. I'm assuming that this is the piece of code responsible which is just the default method VS made up for me.

```
 this._adapter.DeleteCommand = new global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand();
            this._adapter.DeleteCommand.Connection = this.Connection;
            this._adapter.DeleteCommand.CommandText = @"DELETE FROM [Employers Contacts]
                         WHERE        (@IsNull_Company = 1 AND Company IS NULL) OR
                         (Company = @Original_Company) AND (@IsNull_Contact = 1 AND Contact IS NULL) OR
                         (Contact = @Original_Contact) AND (@IsNull_Title = 1 AND Title IS NULL) OR
                         (Title = @Original_Title) AND (@IsNull_Phone = 1 AND Phone IS NULL) OR
                         (Phone = @Original_Phone) AND (Cell = @Original_Cell) OR
                         (@IsNull_Cell = 1 AND Cell IS NULL) AND (@IsNull_Status_TWS = 1 AND Status_TWS IS NULL) OR
                         (Status_TWS = @Original_Status_TWS) AND (@IsNull_Email = 1 AND Email IS NULL) OR
                         (Email = @Original_Email) AND (@IsNull_Region = 1 AND Region IS NULL) OR
                         (Region = @Original_Region) AND (@IsNull_Hiring = 1 AND Hiring IS NULL) OR
                         (Hiring = @Original_Hiring) AND (Industry = @Original_Industry)";
            this._adapter.DeleteCommand.CommandType = global::System.Data.CommandType.Text;
            this._adapter.DeleteCommand.Parameters.Add(new global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@IsNull_Company", global::System.Data.SqlDbType.Int, 0, global::System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, 0, 0, "", global::System.Data.DataRowVersion.Original, true, null, "", "", ""));
            this._adapter.DeleteCommand.Parameters.Add(new global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@Original_Company", global::System.Data.SqlDbType.Variant, 1024, global::System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, 0, 0, "", global::System.Data.DataRowVersion.Original, false, null, "", "", ""));
            this._adapter.DeleteCommand.Parameters.Add(new global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@IsNull_Contact", global::System.Data.SqlDbType.Int, 0, global::System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, 0, 0, "", global::System.Data.DataRowVersion.Original, true, null, "", "", ""));
            this._adapter.DeleteCommand.Parameters.Add(new global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@Original_Contact", global::System.Data.SqlDbType.Variant, 1024, global::System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, 0, 0, "", global::System.Data.DataRowVersion.Original, false, null, "", "", ""));
            this._adapter.DeleteCommand.Parameters.Add(new global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@IsNull_Title", global::System.Data.SqlDbType.Int, 0, global::System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, 0, 0, "", global::System.Data.DataRowVersion.Original, true, null, "", "", ""));
            this._adapter.DeleteCommand.Parameters.Add(new global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@Original_Title", global::System.Data.SqlDbType.Variant, 1024, global::System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, 0, 0, "", global::System.Data.DataRowVersion.Original, false, null, "", "", ""));
            this._adapter.DeleteCommand.Parameters.Add(new global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@IsNull_Phone", global::System.Data.SqlDbType.Int, 0, global::System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, 0, 0, "", global::System.Data.DataRowVersion.Original, true, null, "", "", ""));
            this._adapter.DeleteCommand.Parameters.Add(new global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@Original_Phone", global::System.Data.SqlDbType.Variant, 1024, global::System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, 0, 0, "", global::System.Data.DataRowVersion.Original, false, null, "", "", ""));
            this._adapter.DeleteCommand.Parameters.Add(new global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@Original_Cell", global::System.Data.SqlDbType.Variant, 1024, global::System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, 0, 0, "", global::System.Data.DataRowVersion.Original, false, null, "", "", ""));
            this._adapter.DeleteCommand.Parameters.Add(new global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@IsNull_Cell", global::System.Data.SqlDbType.Int, 0, global::System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, 0, 0, "", global::System.Data.DataRowVersion.Original, true, null, "", "", ""));
            this._adapter.DeleteCommand.Parameters.Add(new global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@IsNull_Status_TWS", global::System.Data.SqlDbType.Int, 0, global::System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, 0, 0, "", global::System.Data.DataRowVersion.Original, true, null, "", "", ""));
            this._adapter.DeleteCommand.Parameters.Add(new global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@Original_Status_TWS", global::System.Data.SqlDbType.Variant, 1024, global::System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, 0, 0, "", global::System.Data.DataRowVersion.Original, false, null, "", "", ""));
            this._adapter.DeleteCommand.Parameters.Add(new global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@IsNull_Email", global::System.Data.SqlDbType.Int, 0, global::System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, 0, 0, "", global::System.Data.DataRowVersion.Original, true, null, "", "", ""));
            this._adapter.DeleteCommand.Parameters.Add(new global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@Original_Email", global::System.Data.SqlDbType.Variant, 1024, global::System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, 0, 0, "", global::System.Data.DataRowVersion.Original, false, null, "", "", ""));
            this._adapter.DeleteCommand.Parameters.Add(new global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@IsNull_Region", global::System.Data.SqlDbType.Int, 0, global::System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, 0, 0, "", global::System.Data.DataRowVersion.Original, true, null, "", "", ""));
            this._adapter.DeleteCommand.Parameters.Add(new global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@Original_Region", global::System.Data.SqlDbType.Variant, 1024, global::System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, 0, 0, "", global::System.Data.DataRowVersion.Original, false, null, "", "", ""));
            this._adapter.DeleteCommand.Parameters.Add(new global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@IsNull_Hiring", global::System.Data.SqlDbType.Int, 0, global::System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, 0, 0, "", global::System.Data.DataRowVersion.Original, true, null, "", "", ""));
            this._adapter.DeleteCommand.Parameters.Add(new global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@Original_Hiring", global::System.Data.SqlDbType.Variant, 1024, global::System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, 0, 0, "", global::System.Data.DataRowVersion.Original, false, null, "", "", ""));
            this._adapter.DeleteCommand.Parameters.Add(new global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@Original_Industry", global::System.Data.SqlDbType.Variant, 1024, global::System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, 0, 0, "", global::System.Data.DataRowVersion.Original, false, null, "", "", ""));
```

Judging from the error message I have no clue what @IsNull_Conta is I think it cut off part of @IsNull_Contact but I don't know why.

Edit: The actual method where the error is taking place is

```
private void employer_ContactsBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to make these changes? (any records deleted or changed " +
                "can not be reverted)", "Confirm Change", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
            if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                this.Validate();
                this.employer_ContactsBindingSource.EndEdit();
                this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this.clientEmployerDataSet);
                MessageBox.Show("Your action has been successful");
            }
        }
```

The error taking place on the 
"this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this.clientEmployerDataSet);" line.

Comment: Show the code which deletes something off the server

Comment: @Serg I edited the question

Comment: `UpdateAll()` will do his job by calling table adapters methods in an order. Somehow  generated code of the delete in the adapter  for `[Employers Contacts]` fails to set  `@IsNull_Company` parameter.

Comment: I found the issue, for whatever reason in the autogenerated code the first set of empty quotes that's in the parameters.add should contain the name of the column which it should be looking at. Now why it didn't autogenerate I have no clue as I went through this process for 2 other tables which both already had it generated

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the column you are looking at in the first pair of empty quotes in parameters.add

it should read:

```
this._adapter.DeleteCommand.Parameters.Add(new global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@IsNull_Company", global::System.Data.SqlDbType.Int, 0, global::System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, 0, 0, "Company", global::System.Data.DataRowVersion.Original, true, null, "", "", ""));
this._adapter.DeleteCommand.Parameters.Add(new global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@Original_Company", global::System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, 255, global::System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, 0, 0, "Company", global::System.Data.DataRowVersion.Original, false, null, "", "", ""));
this._adapter.DeleteCommand.Parameters.Add(new global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@IsNull_Contact", global::System.Data.SqlDbType.Int, 0, global::System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, 0, 0, "Contact", global::System.Data.DataRowVersion.Original, true, null, "", "", ""));
this._adapter.DeleteCommand.Parameters.Add(new global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@Original_Contact", global::System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, 255, global::System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, 0, 0, "Contact", global::System.Data.DataRowVersion.Original, false, null, "", "", ""));
this._adapter.DeleteCommand.Parameters.Add(new global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@IsNull_Title", global::System.Data.SqlDbType.Int, 0, global::System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, 0, 0, "Title", global::System.Data.DataRowVersion.Original, true, null, "", "", ""));
this._adapter.DeleteCommand.Parameters.Add(new global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@Original_Title", global::System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, 255, global::System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, 0, 0, "Title", global::System.Data.DataRowVersion.Original, false, null, "", "", ""));
this._adapter.DeleteCommand.Parameters.Add(new global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@IsNull_Phone", global::System.Data.SqlDbType.Int, 0, global::System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, 0, 0, "Phone", global::System.Data.DataRowVersion.Original, true, null, "", "", ""));
this._adapter.DeleteCommand.Parameters.Add(new global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@Original_Phone", global::System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, 255, global::System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, 0, 0, "Phone", global::System.Data.DataRowVersion.Original, false, null, "", "", ""));
this._adapter.DeleteCommand.Parameters.Add(new global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@Original_Cell", global::System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, 255, global::System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, 0, 0, "Cell", global::System.Data.DataRowVersion.Original, false, null, "", "", ""));
this._adapter.DeleteCommand.Parameters.Add(new global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@IsNull_Cell", global::System.Data.SqlDbType.Int, 0, global::System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, 0, 0, "Cell", global::System.Data.DataRowVersion.Original, true, null, "", "", ""));
this._adapter.DeleteCommand.Parameters.Add(new global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@IsNull_Status_TWS", global::System.Data.SqlDbType.Int, 0, global::System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, 0, 0, "Status_TWS", global::System.Data.DataRowVersion.Original, true, null, "", "", ""));
this._adapter.DeleteCommand.Parameters.Add(new global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@Original_Status_TWS", global::System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, 255, global::System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, 0, 0, "Status_TWS", global::System.Data.DataRowVersion.Original, false, null, "", "", ""));
this._adapter.DeleteCommand.Parameters.Add(new global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@IsNull_Email", global::System.Data.SqlDbType.Int, 0, global::System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, 0, 0, "Email", global::System.Data.DataRowVersion.Original, true, null, "", "", ""));
this._adapter.DeleteCommand.Parameters.Add(new global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@Original_Email", global::System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, 255, global::System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, 0, 0, "Email", global::System.Data.DataRowVersion.Original, false, null, "", "", ""));
this._adapter.DeleteCommand.Parameters.Add(new global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@IsNull_Region", global::System.Data.SqlDbType.Int, 0, global::System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, 0, 0, "Region", global::System.Data.DataRowVersion.Original, true, null, "", "", ""));
this._adapter.DeleteCommand.Parameters.Add(new global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@Original_Region", global::System.Data.SqlDbType.NChar, 255, global::System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, 0, 0, "Region", global::System.Data.DataRowVersion.Original, false, null, "", "", ""));
this._adapter.DeleteCommand.Parameters.Add(new global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@IsNull_Hiring", global::System.Data.SqlDbType.Int, 0, global::System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, 0, 0, "Hiring", global::System.Data.DataRowVersion.Original, true, null, "", "", ""));
this._adapter.DeleteCommand.Parameters.Add(new global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@Original_Hiring", global::System.Data.SqlDbType.Bit, 1, global::System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, 0, 0, "Hiring", global::System.Data.DataRowVersion.Original, false, null, "", "", ""));
this._adapter.DeleteCommand.Parameters.Add(new global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@Original_Industry", global::System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, 255, global::System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, 0, 0, "Industry", global::System.Data.DataRowVersion.Original, false, null, "", "", ""));
```